# C# , SQL update multiple rows

Tags: c#, sql

i have a question regarding an efficient way to update multiple rows via SQL.

Basiclly i have a query i need to run on different RowIDs:

```
UPDATE TableName SET Column = (some number) WHERE RowID = (some number)
```

if to be more specific this is a better example:

```
UPDATE TableName SET Column = 5 WHERE RowID = 1000
UPDATE TableName SET Column = 10 WHERE RowID = 1001
UPDATE TableName SET Column = 30 WHERE RowID = 1002
..
```

I'd like to know how should i build the update query command on C# (or just give me an example of the resulted query i should get to) so once i use ExecuteQuery it will run all of these commands at one piece and not by executing each command.

***edited:***
I have another problem, can you also explain what about dynamic situation in which not necessarly the row i want to update exist already, in that case i need to insert instead of update. to explain better, back to my example lets say i want to do

```
UPDATE TableName SET Column = 5 WHERE RowID = 1000
INSERT INTO TableName [RowID, Column] VALUES (1001, 20)
UPDATE TableName SET Column = 30 WHERE RowID = 1002
..
```

The meaning of this is that i need to check if the row exist, if so i'd use update otherwise i'll have to insert it.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you confirm which database product and version you're using? For modern SQL Server (>= 2008), you'd be looking at using a table-valued parameter and a `MERGE` statement

Answer (score 9):

You could use a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) to store your records, insert, delete or change rows and update all changes in one batch by using SqlDataAdapter's [UpdateBatchSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.updatebatchsize.aspx)(0 means no limit):

```
public static void BatchUpdate(DataTable dataTable,Int32 batchSize)
{
    // Assumes GetConnectionString() returns a valid connection string.
    string connectionString = GetConnectionString();

    // Connect to the AdventureWorks database.
    using (SqlConnection connection = new 
      SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {

        // Create a SqlDataAdapter.
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

        // Set the UPDATE command and parameters.
        adapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(
            "UPDATE Production.ProductCategory SET "
            + "Name=@Name WHERE ProductCategoryID=@ProdCatID;", 
            connection);
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", 
           SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Name");
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@ProdCatID", 
           SqlDbType.Int, 4, "ProductCategoryID");
         adapter.UpdateCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;

        // Set the INSERT command and parameter.
        adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(
            "INSERT INTO Production.ProductCategory (Name) VALUES (@Name);", 
            connection);
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", 
          SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Name");
        adapter.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;

        // Set the DELETE command and parameter.
        adapter.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand(
            "DELETE FROM Production.ProductCategory "
            + "WHERE ProductCategoryID=@ProdCatID;", connection);
        adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("@ProdCatID", 
          SqlDbType.Int, 4, "ProductCategoryID");
        adapter.DeleteCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;

        // Set the batch size.
        adapter.UpdateBatchSize = batchSize;

        // Execute the update.
        adapter.Update(dataTable);
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aadf8fk2.aspx

I assume you're misunderstanding how the dbms works internally. This

```
UPDATE TableName SET Column = 5 WHERE RowID = 1000;
UPDATE TableName SET Column = 5 WHERE RowID = 1002;
```

is the same as

```
UPDATE TableName SET Column = 5 WHERE RowID IN(1000,2002);
```

The dbms will update all affected records one by one anyway even if you would write a statement like `UPDATE table SET value=1` which would affect every record in the table. By updating in one batch you ensure that all updates(deletes,inserts)are submitted to the database instead of one roundtrip for every statement.

Comment: I am viewing the update code (since it's the most relevant to my question) and i didn't quite understand what is the resulted query at the end and why is it efficient? it looks like like your'e building the query im trying to avoid of isn't it ?

Comment: The dbms will update all affected records one by one anyway even if you would write a statement like `UPDATE table SET value=1` which would affect every record in the table. By updating in one batch you ensure that all updates(deletes,inserts)are commited at once  in the same transaction.

Comment: It should be noted that `Update(dataTable)` is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1z2bkx2.aspx) not to batch the updates: "It should be noted that these statements are not performed as a batch process; each row is updated individually.", and that batches and transactions are two orthogonal concepts in SQL.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Of course, every modified row in the DataTable will create an individual update/insert/delete statement. But by setting [DataAdapter's UpdateBatchSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aadf8fk2.aspx) to <>1 you're avoiding roundtrips to the database for every statement by submitting them in one batch.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: To your second argument, you're dead right! You can easily [create a Transaction and assign multiple commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k2hy99x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to it. Sorry for lumping together both.

Answer (score 1):

Use `MERGE`:

```
MERGE INTO TableName
   USING (
          VALUES (1000, 5), 
                 (1001, 10), 
                 (1002, 30)
         ) AS source (RowID, Column_name)
      ON TableName.RowID = source.RowID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE 
      SET Column_name = source.Column_name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (RowID, Column_name) 
      VALUES (RowID, Column_name);
```

Rather than hard-coding/dynamic SQL, the `MERGE` statement could be encapsulated into a stored proc that takes a [table-valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx).

Comment: Just came across this https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/